# Client can't start handshaking with server and returns nil ('upgrade' token is not found)

Tags: go, websocket

I am trying to implement websocket from Gorilla Websocket package in Go. My client starts open connection like this:

```
**index.html**

      var websocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/stats');

      websocket.onopen = function(event) {
        console.log("Cnnected");
      };

      websocket.onerror = function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      };
... some other websocket methods...
```

In my server side, I simply tried to add upgrade token in connection header like this:

```
**websocket.go**

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    CheckOrigin:     func(r *http.Request) bool { return true },
}


func Upgrade(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (*websocket.Conn, error) {


    // get websocket connection here
    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return ws, err
    }
    // returns our new websocket connection
    return ws, nil
}
```

However, it returns nil and the error message shows up on the screen like this:

> Bad Request websocket: the client is not using the websocket protocol:
> 'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
> (Bad Request)

I am not sure why the function Upgrade can not get connection and return ws.

Comment: Did you find the solution for it?